# Reading small separated chunks of a large file (C++)

Tags: c++, file, io, binary, buffer

I am reading a proprietary binary data file format. The format is basically header, data, size_of_previous_data, header, data, size_of_previous_data, header, data, size_of_previous_data, ...
Part of the header includes the number of bytes of the next chunk of data as well as its size being listed immediately after the data. The header is 256 bytes, the data is typically ~ 2MB and the size_of_previous_data is a 32 bit int.

The files are generally large ~GB, and I often have to search through tens of them for the data I want. In order to do this, the first thing I do in my code is idex each of the files, i.e. read in just the headers and record the location of the associated data (file and byte number). My code basically ready the header using fstream::read(), checks the data size, skips the data using fstream::seekg(), then reads in the size_of_previous_data, then repeats until I reach the end of the file.

My problem is that this indexing is painfully slow. The data is on an internal 7200 rpm hard drive on my Windows 10 laptop and Task manager shows that my hard drive usage is maxed out, but I am only getting read speeds of about 1.5 MB/s with response times typically >70 ms. I am reading the file using a std::fstream using fstream::get() to read the headers and fstream::seekg() to move to the next header.

I have profiled my code and almost the entire time is spent in the fstream::read() code to read the size_of_previous_data value. I presume that when I do this the data immediately after this is buffered so my fstream::read() to get the next header takes practically no time.

So I am wondering if there is a way to optimise this? Almost my entire buffer in any buffered read is likely to be wasted (97% of it, if it is an 8kB buffer). Is there a way to shrink this and is it likely to be worth it (perhaps underlying OS buffers too in a way I cannot change)?

Comment: why dont you read all the files at the beginning? GBs of RAM is usually fine, while it is not very surprising that searching files of GB size is slow

Comment: If the size of the data is stored in the header already, why not skip the `size_of_previous_data` as well when you seek past the data? You could save reading that until you need to read the data itself, and use it as a kind of checksum then. And if you only read 256 bytes at a time, then you don't need a buffer larger than that.

Comment: Try memory mapping your file, if your operating system supports it.  The operating system will handle reading of chunks into memory for you.

Comment: @tobi303 The total size of the files I need to read is 11 GB at the moment, but I am currently working on test data and this will increase to 44 GB soon, then even more. My laptop has 8 GB ram, so all I'll do by reading it all in is cause thrashing I guess.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude That will just postpone the actual disk read to when I read the next header. At the moment reading the header is only fast because that data gets cached when I read the size_of_previous_data value. Can I force fstream and the OS to only use a 256 byte buffer?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Is memory mapping likely to be significantly faster? Or will it just do exacly what I am doing under the hood? This is the crux of my question. I am asking if anyone already knows a good strategy to do this or if I need to spend a lot of time testing things like memory mapss and potentially find there is no noticeable change in performance.

Comment: I suggest you read data to the buffer in some large chunks (multiplication of average data part, the best if aligned to filesystem page size - for example around 100M) instead of doing seekg every time, and then move in the buffer.

Comment: Since memory mapping is a platform or OS specific feature, you'll have to consult your operating system API.  There is no standard for memory mapping feature.  You may be able to set the paging size (or chunk size).  The OS can take advantage of any hardware support (such as DMA controllers).  The best answer to "is it faster" is to profile.

Comment: Doing one read of 256 bytes will always be faster than one read of 4 bytes followed by one read of 256 bytes. Not much, I admit, but it will be faster. :) At least *try* it before dismissing it right of the bat.

Comment: Another thing you might try is to simply read the whole file in 2 or 3  megabyte chunks. And then "seek" through the memory buffers to find the headers (and possible `size_of_previous_data`). Discard the data and only save the headers for your index. Sequential reads of a file should be faster, especially with caching and possible pre-fetching. You of course have to be able to handle the case where no header exists in a chunk you've read, and exists somewhere in the next chunk.

Comment: *Is memory mapping likely to be significantly faster?* It's almost impossible for memory mapping to be faster if you never reread the same data. A simple read involves finding the data on disk and copying it into the user-space buffer. Getting the data from a memory map involves creating a virtual memory mapping for the file region, then reading the data from disk and populating the memory. That "creating a virtual memory mapping for the file region" is expensive and slow. If you don't ever reread that data, it's almost certainly not worth it.  The real advantage of `mmap()` is simple code.

Comment: *I am only getting read speeds of about 1.5 MB/s with response times typically >70 ms*  Is this the only drive on the system?  That sounds like your program's IO is contending with other IO operations.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that a disk seek takes about 10 ms (from [Latency Numbers Every Programmer Should Know](https://gist.github.com/jboner/2841832)), your file is 11 GB consisting of 2 MB chunks, the theoretical minimum running time is 5500 * 10 ms = 55 seconds.

If you're already in that order of magnitude, the most effective way of speeding this up might be to buy an SSD.

Comment: *Assuming that a disk seek takes about 10 ms* That's actually pretty optimistic.  7,200 RPM SATA disks are usually more in the 15 ms range, and 5,400 RPM drives can get well over 20 ms.  But I wonder about the bandwidth from the disk.  2 MB in 70 ms is only 28 MB/sec.  Even assuming that 20 ms of that 70 ms is seek time, that means the disk is only moving 40 MB/sec.  That's low, and there may be other hardware bottlenecks along the data path, meaning an SSD won't help much.

Comment: If I understood the question correctly, only 256 bytes need to be read to construct the index, not the full 2 MB. So then seek time becomes the bottleneck, not bandwidth.